# Convert String of lists of floats to List of Lists of floats in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to convert a string containing floats to a list. Basically, I have a text file with a bunch of arrays listed, and I don't know how to gather them in haskell.

Input:

```
"[0.0, 21.05263157894737, 450.56721805219945, 450.5625302466032]
[0.0, 42.10526315789474, 350.6536813941797, 346.7624393708003]
[0.0, 189.47368421052633, 447.5003638411328, 352.12736129109106]
[0.0, 210.5263157894737, 351.9493076378216, 347.65906596838636]"
```

Just a small snippit of the string.

Desired Output:

```
[0.0, 21.05263157894737, 450.56721805219945, 450.5625302466032]
[0.0, 42.10526315789474, 350.6536813941797, 346.7624393708003]
[0.0, 189.47368421052633, 447.5003638411328, 352.12736129109106]
[0.0, 210.5263157894737, 351.9493076378216, 347.65906596838636]
```

All as lists.

I've tried going through and converting characters, but It's all broken down.

The tiny bit I do have just lists all the values

```
main = do
   let args = "output.txt"
   content <- readFile (args)
   print(linesOfFiles)
```

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Hint: use `read` from Prelude.

Comment: You say the file has a bunch of arrays (or lists?), but your sample input only shows one list. Where are the others? Might there (or must there) be whitespace or other characters between them? Does the listing of lists end with a particular character or string, or does it go to the end of the file? Can there be extra whitespace at the end of the file?

Comment: @dfeuer Noted. there are new lines between them. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: @DannyuNDos I've tried to use the read function, but I'm not sure how to do so correctly. Whenever I try, It says I need to create the types Float and Int.

Comment: each list separated by newline `"\n"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the lines of the file separated by newlines, it can be transformed into list of strings using [lines](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) function. Then [read](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) function can be used on every element of that list:

```
readListOfFloats :: String -> [Float]
readListOfFloats = read

main = do
   let args = "output.txt"
   content <- readFile args
   print $ map readListOfFloats $ lines content
```

Or:

```
main = do
   let args = "output.txt"
   content <- readFile args
   print $ map (read :: String -> [Float]) $ lines content
```

Both options will work as long as the type of `read` function is explicitly specified. The compiler can't infer it, because the developer is the only one who knows, which type of input to expect.